# Failure writing sector 0x13407f8 to hd0 - how to check disks if they are not yet accessible?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, initramfs

**I cannot boot Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Lenovo Thinkpad after a reboot given with the REISUB sequence.**

Error message on initial black screen is "error: Failure writing sector 0x13407f8 to hd0": the only peculiar thing about the insurgence of this error is that last time I rebooted the system there was an external drive plugged in.

After that initial error message, I get messages about **"Busybox"** and an `(initramfs)` prompt. I give "exit" and error messages (**"failed command write DMA"**) start pouring on the screen until I give another REISUB.

**There are on this site several questions that involve the error message "error: Failure writing sector 0xYYYYYYYYYY to hd0"**. Some of them mention, as in my case the `initramfs` prompt.

For all of these questions there aren't real answers; just **very sketchy comments about running checks on the hard disk**, like [Smartmontools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools).

The problem the OP's find with those comments is always the same: **how can I run those checks when I have no running system yet?** And the comment writer usually disappears.

**I'd like to receive a full-fledged answer** that explains the following points:

- is it possible that this problem is due to a now missing external drive (I cannot test it today, as that external drive is elsewhere)
- how could I use Smartmontools or others when Ubuntu is not yet up?

  - is there some sort of "minimal boot" (like starting Windows while pressing both SHIFT keys) that will give me at least a bash prompt?
  - can I perform disk checks from inside the `initramfs` prompt?

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* earlier this year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/msantic), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.  *This applies to Ubuntu Core 18 too*

Comment: You can run SMART tools from *live* media; it's the safest option, as you want the drive *idle* and not being used (ie. not booted) as if there are problems, you want to save any remaining life to getting any non-backed up data left, and don't want to make it worse (*by using it - at least not until you've got a plan of action knowing all the facts*).  Using the SMART technology reads data from drive electronics (*not actual drive; it's idle!*) as almost every drive made in mid-1990s has SMART due to design.  You need a booted system (not *initial ram disk/file-system* as you ask!)

Comment: My mistake. I have Ubuntu 20. Correcting the text. By doublechecking the busybox prompt `BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.1) built-in shell (ash)` I was able to infer precisely my Ubuntu 20 version.

Comment: @guiverc - Thank you, but sorry - I cannot make any use of your words. Live? Idle? initial ram disk/file-system? What is all that? Dunno. Are there specific answers to my questions?

Comment: Idle, in that you want to *assess* the drive (using its SMART) when its *idle*, ie. not being used. You do that by either removing the drive & using it as an external drive on another computer (ie. *using a different computers OS as the operating/operational drive*) **OR** boot a thumb-drive and use the *Try Ubuntu* option so you're using it only as a *live* system (ie. no install is necessary; the system is lost on reboot/shutdown).   Your listed package does not match a patched 20.04 system; a correct response for 20.04 should be `1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.4` ???  *a clue maybe?*